# How to solve: constructor parameter immutable

Tags: ios, swift

To refactor a function, I'm trying to put it globally available:

```
func loadUsers(_ users: [User] , _ tableView: UITableView) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("Users")
    usersRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {

                users.removeAll()
                ...
    }
```

I'm receiving:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'users' is a 'let' constant

When I set:

```
func loadUsers(_ users: [User] , _ tableView: UITableView) {

    let usersRef = firebase.child("Users")
    usersRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {

            if var users = users as? [User] {
                users.removeAll()
                ...
}
```

It builds and works, but I receive constantly the warnings:

> Conditional cast from '[User]' to '[User]' always succeeds
>
> And
>   Non-optional expression of type '[User]' used in a check for optionals

What is the best approach to solve my issue? Help is very appreciated.

**PS**, I need the original values from `users` to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the first set of code is because parameters are immutable.

The errors in the second set of code are because you are trying to use `if let` with a non-optional constant and you are trying to cast to the same type making the cast pointless.

Since you want the original array to be modified by this function you need to make it an `inout` parameter:

```
func loadUsers(_ users: inout [User] , _ tableView: UITableView) {
    let usersRef = firebase.child("Users")
    usersRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            users.removeAll()
            ...
}
```

You now also need to add an `&` before the `var` that you pass to the `users` parameter.

Comment: I didn't notice the use of the closure. The link you reference is a better solution to what you need to do.